# Can the brain be enhanced by adding more neurons?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, brain, cognitive-enhancement

I was wondering of ways to enhance the brain. Couldn't we add a sort of substance to improve the brain? Will it somehow adapt? The brain should 'wire up' the new substance to the existing one.

As far as I know, the brain is just neural connections, so why just not add more connections? I mean, why not add more neurons, therefore enhancing the human mind, getting closer to answering questions like "Does God exist?".

Maybe modifying DNA to produce more neurons, making the brain bigger...?
In my opinion the future lies in enhancing the mind, what ways are there to do that?

P.S - I'm only 16 y/o.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you still have trouble with this, please visit the [ask] page or [meta].

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to tackle this question from a developmental vantage point.

You hit the nail on the head by saying

> ...the brain is <strike>just</strike> neural connections...

Indeed, the power of the brain is based on the connectivity of its neurons. The number of connections is what counts, not just absolute neuronal numbers. In fact, **more than 50% of neurons are lost during development**, as a result of limiting [trophic support](http://www.els.net/WileyCDA/ElsArticle/refId-a0000803.html) from the target tissue they are destined to innervate. This neuronal cell death facilitates proper connections in the nervous system. The [apoptotic cells](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/child-health/research/developmental-biology-and-cancer-programme/cancer/jonathan-hams-research-group/mechanisms) are indeed unwanted in the nervous system, and apoptosis continues throughout life and is the central mechanism for the removal of surplus, unwanted, damaged or aged cells. [(Mazarakis, 1998)](https://fn.bmj.com/content/77/3/F165). Leaving them could result in aberrant functionality. For instance, it is claimed that [synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_basis_of_synesthesia) *may* be linked to incomplete neural cell death in development, leading to aberrant connections between the senses. Many sysnesthetes for instance see certain numbers appear in specific colors. These cross-sensory associations are thought to be caused by faulty cell death between the respective sensory systems in the central nervous system (the brain).

In effect, adding neurons to an existing functioning brain is expected to lead to disruptive brain function, rather than improvement.

The practical limitations of injecting additional neurons are mountainous -

- Where would you obtain viable neurons from? Stem cells?
- In the case of stem cells there's a chance of  uncontrolled growth (cancer);
- If the neurons don't come from a genetic identical individual there's the issue of immunological graft rejection;
- How would you deliver the neurons to their appropriate position in the brain? Just drill a diffuse set of holes in the skull? How would you reach the deeper layers of the brain? How would you contain the neurons to the brain and prevent 'leakage' to unwanted sites in the body, such as the blood stream?

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Mazarakis, *Archives Disease Childhood* (1997); **77**:F165–F70](https://fn.bmj.com/content/77/3/F165)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll continue to research the field because I think there's a lot of potential. A lot of companies try to improve the brain with electronics, but what about DNA? Your answer doesn't exactly give yes or no, but I guess that's because it's still a new field? Do you think it'll be possible for humans to improve their minds (memory, cognitive skils...)?

Comment: @NovaliumCompany - I focused on the neuron part. The question is quite broad and therefore I gave a focused answer.

Comment: Sorry, which question do you answer and what is it's answer?

Comment: @NovaliumCompany - I answered - *I mean, ...why not add more neurons...,* -

Comment: Got it, thank you. You state that the number of neurons don't matter, it's the connections. So making more connections should result in the 'enchancement' I'm talking about. Are there any known ways to make more connections, maybe genetically?

Comment: @NovaliumCompany - The point is that these connections need to make sense. But I wouldn't know how to do it genetically.

Comment: @NovaliumCompany Surely accomplishing the same thing using DNA as could be accomplished by direct injection would be monumentally more treacherous than it already is!

Comment: @AliceD Great answer.  You may also be interested in: http://sitn.hms.harvard.edu/flash/2018/worlds-first-clinical-trial-treat-parkinsons-disease-stem-cells/

Comment: one article has shown that mice with confirmed epileptic sizures can benefit from transplanting interneurons which in turn deminished the siezures
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23644485